# How to customize journal vouchers form in odoo?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, odoo-8

In the accounts module(Journal vouchers column) I want to create a separate button for credit and debit entry instead of making a selection from the drop down.I am not getting in which file can I edit this.Instead of create button I want create debit entry and create credit entry buttons.[image]

Answer (score 0):

This require to develop an extension in the template and javascript widget, like this:

You need to include a template that insert the button like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<template>
    <t t-extend="ListView.buttons">
        <t t-jquery="button.oe_list_add" t-operation="after">
            <button class="oe_button oe_new_button oe_highlight" type="button">New Button</button>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
```

Next you need to extend the widget ListView like this:

```
instance.web.ListView.include({
    load_list: function(data) {
        if (this.$buttons) {
            this.$buttons.find('.oe_new_button').click(this.proxy('do_new_button')) ;
        }
    },
    do_new_button: function () {
        //implement your clic logic here  
    }
});
```

May be this is useful...

Comment: your_module/static/src/xml/your_xml.xml and create one template tag and put this code in .xml file

Comment: in accounts voucher module there is no xml folder inside static folder

Comment: you create in your own custome module

Comment: I am getting this error, XMLSyntaxError: Extra content at the end of the document, line 10, column 1 for adding your 2nd para of code(instance.web)                    Should i write it in separate file?